# UITabBar setTintColor is not working after [_window setRootViewController]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a weird problem. Whenever my application launches, I do the following in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor mainLightBlue]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor mainLightBlue]];

    [IJContext setDefaultContext:[[IJContext alloc] init]];
    RKLogConfigureFromEnvironment();
    return YES;
}
```

Then, if my user successfully logs in, I do the following in the AppDelegate:

```
-(void)presentNewsFeed
{
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelDebug);
    UIViewController *newTopViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainiPadStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GlobalInitialSliding"];
    [_window setRootViewController:newTopViewController];
}
```

At this point, the setTintColor is working fine. Now, whenever a user logs out, I call:

```
- (void)presentLoginScreen
{
    UIViewController *newTopViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainiPadStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
    [_window setRootViewController:newTopViewController];
}
```

Which is again located in the AppDelegate. If the logs back in, I call once again `presentNewsFeed`. However, on that second time, the setTintColor is no longer working, and all my tabs do not actually have a tintColor whenever their are selected. So my users can't actually know which tab is selected. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had another declaration of the `tintColor` in a `viewController` and it was messing with the one in the `appDelegate`!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your question:
Then, if my user successfully logs in, I do the following in the `AppDelegate`:

```
-(void)presentNewsFeed           
{ ... }
```

It means your first screen is *Login Screen* then why do not you set `setRootViewController` as **yourLoginScreenViewController**? In your code, You will be also receive a warning such like `Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`? Because when you will do launch you app at that time your window has not **rootViewController** so.

And If you follow my suggestion then it is very easy for you to get **LoginScreen** whenever you **LoggedOut**, By using following code:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Because here your `RootViewController` is your **LoginScreen** so you directly reach at your `RootViewController` and also not worry about re-creation of `RootViewController`.

Comment: Not working. Actually the very first RootViewController is not set by me, but by my storyboard. THEN, I later replicate that first rootViewController in that presentNewsFeed function, in which I no longer have my barTintColor for some reasons...

Comment: Fixed my problem, but it wasn't because of your solution! Sorry... (I was setting the tintColor somewhere else and it conflicted with the original definition in the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for setting flat red color for tabbar

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

for setting image Try this

```
 UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bg"]
                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_indicator"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an image (`1px for width and 49 px for height`) and save it, for example: `tabBg.png`, and then you replace:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor mainLightBlue]];
```

by this:

```
UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBg.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

I hope this helps you.